# Understanding Java 8 Lambda Expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I was reading [this article](https://www.toptal.com/java/why-you-need-to-upgrade-to-java-8-already) on Java 8 and had the following questions/comments I would appreciate some feedback/response.

1) Is the `@FunctionalInterface` declaration necessary for the following code? Or could this same code be executed without it and it is for documentation purposes? It is unclear from whether it is necessary from the article.

```
@FunctionalInterface
private interface DTOSender {
   void send(String accountId, DTO dto);
}

void sendDTO(BisnessModel object, DTOSender dtoSender) {
   //some logic for sending...
   ...
   dtoSender.send(id, dto);
   ...
}
```

2) In general, can a function be passed as an argument to another function in Java 8? My understanding is only data types can be passed as arguments to functions, so I suppose it is not possible as a function is not a data type.

3) Do I need to do anything special to accomplish #2 above or can I just write my definitions of the 2 methods and just pass the one method as a parameter to the other method?

4) Can objects be passed as arguments to another function in Java 8? Do I need to do anything special to accomplish this or can I just write my definitions of the object and method and just pass the object as a parameter to the method?

Comment: (1) Like in most cases [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) holds the answer: "However, the compiler will treat any interface meeting the definition of a functional interface as a functional interface *regardless of whether or not a FunctionalInterface annotation is present on the interface declaration*."

Comment: Thanks - that's what I thought as well but I must have missed that. Can you provide any comment on the other questions?

Comment: Sorry but I am preoccupied right now. BTW you should [ask one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735).

Comment: Thanks for your help - I felt they were related concepts and were sort of small and conditional so I thought I'd just combine them

Comment: I would state that there are no functions in Java. There are only methods – whether static or non-static –, and there is also the interface `Function`.

Comment: Thanks - I am using the terms interchangeably but it is definitely a good idea to make sure I am clearer to avoid these types of ambiguities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `@Functional Interface` is just a hint, so that you don't put more methods into your interface.
2. It can. Many methods on `Stream` take functions as parameter: `Stream.of(1, 2, 3).forEach(System.out::println)`.
3. Lambda is a function **instance**: `Function<Integer, Integer> f = a -> a + 1`. Edit: you can pass a function by name using method reference (see 2., `println` is a regular method).
4. I don't fully get the question. If the method consumes any argument, that is not primitive, it takes an object (everything in java except for primitives is an object).

Comment: Ok thanks. I think this definitely answered my question. So is lambda expressions main benefit for reader clarity purposes?

Comment: @user3216798 there are many benefits. Readability is one of the most apparent

Comment: Is there any direct performance benefit? Or is it primarily for writer and reader benefit?

Comment: I modified my original question a bit - can you respond to #3 above? You referenced stream however can I just simply create 2 random new methods and pass one method as a parameter to the other method or do I need to do anything special?

Comment: @user3216798 I already did in the second point;> `System.out::println` refers to `println` method by name. This is a regular method defined on `PrintStream`.

Comment: I didn't downvote - I thought you answered the question well. So just to clarify - I can pass a method as a paramter to another method without doing anything special/unusual (i.e. outside of their normal definitions)?

Comment: @user3216798 Yes, via [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), which are basically shorthand for lambda expressions that simply invoke a single method. For instance, the  `forEach(System.out::println)` example in this answer is equivalent to `forEach(e -> System.out.println(e))` and it's invoking the `PrintStream#println` method of the `System.out` instance.

Comment: @user3216798 Though _technically_ you aren't passing a _method_ around. Both lambda expressions and method references create instances of a functional interface, and it's the instance of the functional interface you're passing around.

Comment: @Slaw yeah, maybe that's what got someone mad, added a note about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The annotation [@FunctionalInterface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) is not mandadory as the doc states.

In order to pass a function to your method, there has to be a matching functional interface.

```
interface ListFilter<T> {
    boolean test(T item);
}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> filter(List<T> list, ListFilter<T> filter) {
    List<T> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T t : list) {
        if (filter.test(t)) {
            filteredList.add(t);
        }
    }
    return filteredList;
}

public static boolean isNumberGreaterThan2(Integer integer){
    return integer > 2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
    filter(list, new ListFilter<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(Integer item) {
            return item > 2;
        }
    });
    // or
    filter(list, item -> item > 2);
    // or
    filter(list, Main::isNumberGreaterThan2);
}
```

Comment: I would say its implied by the document but it isn't exactly stated. For example, the @ is needed for "override" 'for when it is used; but I guess for "FunctionalInterface" it is not necessary

Comment: So if functions can be passed as parameters to other functions without use of lambda, is the benefit of lambda expression merely for reader clarity purposes?

Comment: @user3216798 yes, it's just a shorthand

Comment: How is the snippet linked to what you're saying. And why are you redefining `println`?

Comment: @Andronicus I was trying to show in the example that to pass an existing function to another, the function that you want to pass must match the functional interface specified as parameter.